# What is the meaning of big in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1596363/synopsis)

> This was **big** for bankers, up until the year 2008 when the global
>   financial crisis hit.

What is the meaning of big in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that this usage of *big* could be considered short for *a big deal*:

> This was a big deal for bankers, up until the year 2008 when the global financial crisis hit.

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/big+deal) defines a *big deal* as:

> **big deal** `Slang` (*n.*) Something of great importance or consequence

You can look up instances of *[this was big for us](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22This%20was%20big%20for%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#tbm=nws&q=%22This%20was%20big%20for%20us%22)* and *[this was a big deal for us](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22This%20was%20a%20big%20deal%20for%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#tbm=nws&q=%22This%20was%20a%20big%20deal%20for%20us%22)* on Google news, and you'll see that the two phrases are both rather common and used in very similar ways.

Answer (score 2):

In this sentence, [big](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/big) means important. Here is a definition:  **important, because of being powerful, or having a lot of influence or a serious effect**.

Here are some other examples:

> He had a **big** decision to make.
>
> There's a **big** difference between starting up a business and just talking about it.
>
> The **big** story in the news this week is the mayor's resignation.